# Setting JMSMessageID on stubbed jms endpoints in camel unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, jms, stub

I have a route that I am testing. I use `stub://jms:queue:whatever` to send/receive messages and extending `CamelTestSupport` for my test classes. I am having an issue with one of the routes that has a bean that uses an idempotent repo to store messages by "message id" for which it reads and stores the JMSMessageID property from exchange.

The problem I run into is that I can't figure out a way to set this property on messages sent on stubbed endpoints. Every time the method that requires this prop is called, the id returns null and i have to handle it as a null pointer. I can do this but the cleanest approach would be to just set the header on the test message. I tried `includeSentJMSMessageId=true` on endpoint, I tried using `sendBodyAndHeader` on producer and passing `"JMSMessageID", "ID: whatever"` in arguments, doesn't appear to work? I read that the driver/connectionfactory is supposed to set the header, but I'm not too familiar with how/where to do this. And since I am using a stubbed end points, I'm not creating any brokers/connectionfactories in my uts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So dont stud out the JMS component replace it with a processor and then add the preferred JMSMessageID in the processor.

Something like this code:

```
  @Test
    void testIdempotency() throws Exception {
        mockOut.expectedMinimumMessageCount(1);
        //specify the route to test
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(context, "your-route-name", enrichRoute -> {
            //replace the from with a end point we can call directly.
            enrichRoute.replaceFromWith("direct:start");

            //replace the jms endpoint with a processor so it can act as the JMS Endpoint.
            enrichRoute.weaveById("jms:queue:whatever").replace().process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    //Set that ID to the one I want to test
                    exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMSMEssageID", "some-value-to-test");
                }
            });
            // add an endpoint at the end to check if received a mesage

            enrichRoute.weaveAddLast().to(mockOut);

        });
        context.start();
        //send some message
        Map<String,Object> sampleMsg = getSampleMessageAsHashMap("REQUEST.json");
        //get the response
        Map<String,Object> response = (Map<String,Object>)template.requestBody("direct:start", sampleMsg);
        // you will need to check if the response is what you expected.
        // Check the headers etc.
        mockOut.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One comment, the stubbing out of endpoints is extremely convenient. One observation I made is that as the exchange passes from one bean to another, the header that I set subsequently does end up on the exchange, but is missing from the original "stubbed" end point. So looks like camel is aware of it just not setting it on the exchange it creates from 1st off stub message. I'm not sure if the weaving stuff is there in the version of camel that is used as it's pretty old. But this is extremely helpful to get desired behavior. Thanks!

Comment: Weaving has been there since the beginning afaik. Unit testing a route should not be dependent on running a full AMQ or any other external provider. With this you can create canned messages and inject them into the camel routes simulating a JMS/HTTP or any other provider system. This makes the unit test fast and easy to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The JMSMessageID can only be set by the *provider*. It cannot be set by a client despite the fact that `javax.jms.Message` has [`setJMSMessageId()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSMessageID-java.lang.String-). As [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSMessageID-java.lang.String-) states:

> This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. This message cannot be used by clients to configure the message ID. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for this. Just to clarify: in my junit 4 test class, I am using a "stub" to send and receive jms messages on a camel route, which is what i am testing. So thinking out loud: in "theory" there should be some way to set this on a message if it's getting consumed ? Since provider is "stubbed" ? What do they mean by "provider" ? I have control over producer and consumer in this instance. Is this a limitation of the camel stub ?

Comment: The *provider* is whatever is providing the JMS client & broker implementation (e.g. ActiveMQ). I'm a messaging guy and not very familiar with Camel so I'm not sure what a *stub* is. I assume it's some way you can mock an actual environment. I also assume you're not providing your own JMS implementation for the stub which is probably what you would need to do in order to set the JMSMessageID.

Comment: This can be done by replacing the JMS component in a unit test with a processor. See answer below.